# C- Checking if the first character in the first comand line arguement contains a particular char

Tags: c, pointers, casting, strcmp, fgetc

If the first character of the first argument == "-" then enter the if statement. The error I get is "passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast" I have also tried this with fgetc, written a little differently, but still get this error. If I cast it I get a core dump. 
    If the argument contains a dash it would be followed by numbers inside the same argument so I cannot just look at argv[1] as a single char, if I could the condition would be as simple as: `if (strcmp(argv[1], "-")==0)`

Function

```
int main (int argc, const char *argv[]){
    const char *test = argv[1];
    if (strcmp(test[0],"-")==0)
        {
          printf("saw there was a dash");
        }
    return 0;}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you are on a *nix (incl. Linux and Mac OS X) system, you might as well use [`getopt(3)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strcmp()` is to compare strings, that is, null terminated `char` arrays. But in here you are comparing two `char`, this will do:

```
if (test[0] == '-')
```

Note the single quotes in `'-'`, that's a `char` literal.

Comment: Oh, of course, thank you. I will select your answer as accepted answer once the time period allows.

Comment: Dereferencing the char ptr s.t. (test[0] == *'-'), removes all warnings from the compiler.